# Dual Boot Ubuntu OS problem. D Drive lost.

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu on my system which already has Windows 7 alongside. After installing the OS, I cannot see the Disk D partition on my Windows OS. I tried "changing the drive letter and paths", but the option is greyed out which means I cannot access it through Windows. On checking the partition through "Diskmgmt.msc", the D Drive has been listed as a Ubuntu partition. What should I do in order to get my data back? The data in the D drive is visible in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you installed ubuntu on the "d" drive partition. That means that the "d" drive uses the ext3 or ext4 file system (Linux) which cannot be accessed from within windows because it is not supported. You can still access NTFS file systems (windows) from within Linux, though.

If you have data on that drive that you need in windows then log in to your ubuntu install and copy them onto an NTFS partition so that windows can see them.